# Unable to call web api because not getting date in correct format to add in url

Tags: angular, api, date

Whenever I am trying to call web api by using value from datepicker, it is displaying date in weird manner resulting bad request from server.

GET  https://lihcode-lufthansa-open-new-v1.p.mashape.com/v1/operations/schedules/sfo/bom/1542738600000?limit=10 400 (Bad Request).

```
 Here date is 154273860000, but I want date in 2018-11-20(yyyy-mm-dd).
```

and here it is my component html for date.

```
<input required matInput #input maxlength="3" 
name="destination" placeholder="Enter destination" 
class="form-control 
[(ngModel)]="flightSchedule.destination">
<mat-hint align="end">Destination airport.             
</mat-form-field>
```

and my modal class is:

```
export class FlightSchedule {

    constructor(
        public destination: string,
        public origin: string,
        public date: string,
        public limit: string
    ) {}

}
```

I need help,  please someone help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: there should not be any constructor in the model class. it should be like this `export class FlightSchedule { public destination: string,
    public origin: string,
    public date: string,
    public limit: string }`. suggest following good code practices.

Comment: How are you adding the date in your `date` string. Please share that code.

Comment: export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  date = new FormControl(moment());


  constructor(private dataService: LufthansaDataService) { }

 flightSchedule = new FlightSchedule('fra', 'fra', '2018-11-20', '10');

  ngOnInit() {  }

 
  onSubmit() {

    this.dataService.getInformation(this.flightSchedule).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  console.log(this.flightSchedule);

  }

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edited

Try to format the date on `ngModelChange` event but you have to assign to another property (formatedDate) and get the date from formatedDate property.

```
<input required matInput #input maxlength="3" 
name="destination" placeholder="Enter destination" 
class="form-control 
[(ngModel)]="flightSchedule.destination"
(ngModelChange)="formater(flightSchedule.date)"> <--- here
```

Add a new property `formatedDate`

```
export class FlightSchedule {
  constructor(
    public destination: string,
    public origin: string,
    public date: string,
    public formatedDate?: string, <--- here
    public limit: string
  ) {}
}
```

Add a function in you class

```
formater(unixTime: number) {
  var date = new Date(unixTime);  
  var myDate = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}T${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}`;
  this.flightSchedule.formatedDate = myDate;
}
```

For momentjs

```
formater(unixTime: number) {
  const date = new Date(unixTime);  
  const myDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm);
  this.flightSchedule.formatedDate = myDate;
}
```

Comment: Sorry wrong parameter passed. Please check the Edited

Comment: It i working perfectly brother.  If i want to add HH:mm, what I need to do.  Please modify the code YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm..  I want to add extra things, but I really appreciate your helps.  Thanks a lot

Comment: are you using momentjs?

Comment: @SheikAlthaf Have a look at moment.js too. They have TS version. It should ease your pain.